# Pronunciation of 大罪

Tags: pronunciation

There's a Japanese manga/anime series called [Nanatsu no taizai (七つの大罪, )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Deadly_Sins_(manga)), which is pronounced as

> ななつのたいざい

as one can clearly hear in [this intro](https://youtu.be/wqEkSBiB2lo?t=25) or see in its [Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%83%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E7%BD%AA_(%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB)).

However, the word 「大罪」is pronounced as「だいざい, as I've found in both a [dictionary](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A4%A7%E7%BD%AA) and [Wikipedia page for cardinal sins](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%83%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E7%BD%AA).

Why is the pronunciation in the show different?

Comment: たいざい is listed in "other forms" of the Jisho page that you linked to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

たいざい is just an alternative reading of 大罪, and is listed perhaps in all decent monolingual dictionaries.

- [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/133167/meaning/m0u/) and 明鏡国語辞典 treat たいざい as the primary reading and だいざい as an alternative.
- [大辞林](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A4%A7%E7%BD%AA) treats だいざい as the primary reading.